# Restrict Login Access to GCP Console for Enterprise

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-security

Is there a way to prevent a user from logging into the GCP console from outside a specific network? I cannot seem to find anything that suggests this can or cannot be done. If an admin picks a bad password, has his/her credentials phished, etc. someone could login and wreak havoc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because Google Cloud Platform is accessible anywhere around the world. All admins should follow best practice guidelines such as the following [US-CERT](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/tips/ST04-002) best password practices article.